# has_one and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, mongoid

I have a `Team` object and a `Game` object.

A `Game` is supposed to have one winner which is a `Team`
A `Team` can be the winner of multiple `Games`

How can I structure this correctly? I'm using Mongoid

This is what I came up with so far...

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_one :winner, :class_name=>Team
end

class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games_won, :class_name=>"Game", :inverse_of => :Game 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider abstracting the win out into its own class, so that:

```
class Game
  has_one :win
end

class Team
  has_many :wins
end

class Win
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :team
end
```

This makes the structure more logical, makes the code simpler, and has other advantages for situations where you might want to start working with wins as a separate resource for other reasons.

Comment: good idea. just tried this. changed Win to Result. but I'm getting undefined method `has_a' for Result:Class. Should it be has_one instead?

Comment: My apologies, it should be `has_one`. I was typing without thinking :)

Comment: no problem, i am getitng some strange stuff though... "When adding a(n) Game to Result#game, Mongoid could not determine the inverse foreign key to set. The attempted key was 'result_id'." This is when i try and do a result = Result.new, then result.game = Game.find(....

Comment: Use the `belongs_to` method on the `Result` class instead, and make sure the results table has columns for `game_id` and `team_id`. My original code had `has_one` on the `Result` class as well, making Rails look for the foreign key on the `games` table. There's a great explanation of the difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association).

Comment: Awesome, looks like it is working now.. (Had issues being able to access MyGame.result. but I restarted rails and now it is looking okay). Just to make sure... when I look at my mongo document for Game I notice it doesn't have a reference to Result (but Result has a reference to Game). For efficiencies sake (since it appears doing game.result will probably yield a bunch of queries), is there a way to keep a reference in Game to all the results?

Comment: Cool :). I haven't used mongo before, so I'm not sure if this is different, but the way Rails structures this normally is that the foreign key is on the belongs_to table. When you call game.result it generates a query that pulls results filtered by game_id. This is perfectly fine. If you want to add a shortcut from game to team as well, you can even use the 'has many through' construct to make your code simpler.

Comment: thanks kaizen, unfortunately mongoid doesn't support the has many through. but this will do for now. cheers